# Adding Glyph based on condition in line graph in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization, linechart

[This is the output that I would be requiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHczM.png)

[This is the output that I am getting at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txZqa.png)

I have added the circle glyphs in my d3 code, but I need to add the glyphs based on the condition that if the month is Jan, only then the circle should appear! For example, in order of 01/2019, 01/2020, 01/2021 the circle should appear only on these dates

`g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataIS)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(parseTime(d.date));})
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.salary + d.bonus); })
            .attr("r", "4") 
            .style("stroke","black")
            .style("stroke-width","2")
            .style("fill", "red" );`

This creates the circles on all the dates, I need to filter and show them only on month Jan

Comment: Could you add a code sample?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your **question** with the code (there is an "edit" button) instead of writing code in the comments. Also, please add all the relevant code ([MCVE]) for receiving a proper answer.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas - have added the code
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Can you filter the data and only add circle if month is January in the data?

I assume that `dataIS` is an array of some kind.

```
g.selectAll("circle")
.data(
  dataIS
  .filter(
    d =>{
      console.log("d is:",JSON.stringify(d,undefined,2));
      return d.date.getMonth() === 0 //only January
    }
  )
)
.enter()
...
```

Comment: @ HMR

g.selectAll("circle") .data( dataIS .filter( d => d.date.getMonth() === 0 //only January ) ) .enter() .append("circle") .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(parseTime(d.date)); }) .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.salary + d.bonus); }) .attr("r", "4") .style("stroke","black") .style("stroke-width","2") .style("fill","darkred"); 

I have added the code which you've given but on running that, the axes and the circles disappear

Comment: @jeet08 Can you press F12 (preferably in Chrome) and see in the console tab of the developer tools if there is an exception. My guess is that `getMonth is not a function` because `d.date` is either undefined or not a date object. You can `console.log(JSON.stringify(d,undefined,2))` just before the `getMonth` (updated answer) and update your question with the  output.

Comment: I tried running the edited code as well and it doesn't produce the output

Comment: @jeet08 If it doesn't produce output it must produce an error or `dataIS` is an empty array. Are you trying it in recent Chrome? The code is in ES2015 and maybe you're trying it in a browser that doesn't support it so there is an error. You can use babel to transpile it or use an older syntax (`d=>...` is the same as `function(d)...`

Comment: On running the code that you provided, the entire graph disappears or there is no change and I get circles on every month! I am not getting an error as such

Comment: @jeet08 Could you maybe provide an example on fiddle? You can use static data for that. I don't see how that's possible with the code you posted but I'm sure that's not all the code of your program.

Comment: @jeet08 http://jsfiddle.net/aK6DP/721/ after the comment `adding circle`

Comment: If you can let me know how to share the code with you, I can send you the entire code!

Comment: @jeet08 You can sign up to bitbucket with your google account, give me your profile name and I'll add you to a team so you can add code to a private team project. Your profile can be found when you click person icon in the left bottom -> `view profile`. My profile can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/amsterdamharu/